# Templavoila loose it's mapping after conversion of database to UTF-8

Tags: templates, encoding, utf-8, mapping, typo3

I'm using TemplaVoila 1.5.5 and TYPO3 4.5.5. I tried to switch a TYPO3 database from `latin1_swedish_ci` (ISO-8859-1) to `utf8_general_ci`. Therefore I wrote a PHP script which converted everything to binary and than everything to utf8_general_ci. Everything seemed to work except TemplaVoila (all other settings in Typo3 were already prepared for UTF-8 but not the database). I got the following message when opening the TYP3 page:

> Couldn't find a Data Structure set for table/row "pages:x". Please
>   select a Data Structure and Template Object first.

If I looked in a template mapping I got the next message that there is no mapping available. In the table `tx_templavoila_tmplobj` in the column `templatemapping` the mapping is stored as BLOB. When converting to UTF-8 everything is gone. Because its binary I can't access it and convert it in an easy way.

How can I keep the mapping? I don't want to map everything new. What can I do?

[Here](http://bugs.typo3.org/view.php?id=2856) there are two proposed solutions but I want to know if there are better ones. In the solution from Michael I also have to map everything again?

What is the fastet way to restore the mapping?

Comment: The fastest way is to remap. If You have huge amount of templates, probably need to make a conversion tool. Regards.

Comment: @Fedir: How would such a conversion tool look like? Is there something like a conversion tool already available?

Comment: Personally, I didn't saw good converters. As I understand, it should be batch PHP script, which explodes mapping data, converts it, implodes back and makes dB updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say if you'll be able to recover the data now that it's been converted, but if you're willing to run your conversion script I have had some success with the following approach:

1. Unserialize the data in the templatemapping field of the tx_templavoila_tmplobj table.
2. Convert the unserialized data array to your target encoding (there is a helper method t3lib_cs::convArray which you might be able to use for this  purpose).
3. Serialize the converted data and save it back to the templatemapping field.

Comment: I have a backup and can start from the beginning ;) I had the similar idea as I read [this](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-templavoila/2009-April/004039.html). I used `utf8_encode` instead of `t3lib_cs::convArray` because I don't know how to include this function from t3lib\class.t3lib_cs.php. Simple include? Now I'm testing but it seems to work ...

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way: just change the field manually back to `mediumtext`. All mappings should be fine again. I know, it's quick and dirty, but worked for me...